# SVG bug on Android

Tags: android, html, css, svg, zurb-foundation

Currently working on a website which works fine in every browser I tested it. It only doesn't work in a standard browser which is ran by my Samsung Galaxy Note tablet. This is a screenshot of the problem:

http://s3.postimg.org/4a6jifj9f/Screenshot_2012_01_02_02_26_42.png

The payment methods get a margin/padding/line-height for no reason. No idea what's going wrong. You can see how it's supposed to be here: http://52.28.84.33/

Thank you all!!

The html:

```
<ul class="payment">
    <li data-tooltip="" aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip" data-selector="tooltip-idfx8fp00" aria-describedby="tooltip-idfx8fp00" title="">
        <img src="#">
    </li>
    <li data-tooltip="" aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip" data-selector="tooltip-idfx8fp01" aria-describedby="tooltip-idfx8fp01" title="">
        <img src="#">
    </li>
    <li data-tooltip="" aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip" data-selector="tooltip-idfx8fp02" aria-describedby="tooltip-idfx8fp02" title="">
         <img src="#">
     </li>
     <li data-tooltip="" aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip" data-selector="tooltip-idfx8fp03" aria-describedby="tooltip-idfx8fp03" title="">
         <img src="#">
     </li>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
.pageFooter .top ul {
    margin: 0 0 1.875rem 0;
    display: none;
}
@media only screen and (min-width:800px) {
    .pageFooter .top ul {
        display: block;
    }
}
.pageFooter .top ul.payment li {
    float: left;
    width: 1.875rem;
    margin: 0 0.9375rem 0 0;
    opacity: 0.65;
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
    transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}
.pageFooter .top ul.payment li:hover {
    opacity: 1; 
}
@media only screen and (min-width:800px) {
    .pageFooter .top ul.payment li {
        width: 25%;
        padding: 0 0.9375rem 0 0;
        margin: 0; 
    } 
}
.pageFooter .top ul.payment li img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: top; 
}
```